# Numerical equivalent of nameValuePair array list?

Tags: java, php, http

I'm dealing with doubles and looking for the "double" equivalent of this...

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",lat));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng",lng));
```

edit//  I'm making a HTTP request, I think need to map the lat value to a php lat variable and the long to a php variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to use `NameValuePair`, there are two possible solutions.

You can convert a `Map` to a `List` of `NameValuePair`:

```
List<NameValuePair> convertParameters(Map<String, Double> parameters) {
    List<NameValuePair> result = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    for (Entry<String, Double> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
        result.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString()));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Or you can implement a new NameValuePair to handle Double values:

```
public class DoubleNameValuePair implements NameValuePair {

    String name;

    double value;

    public DoubleNameValuePair(String name, double value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return Double.toString(value);
    }

}
```

In the latter case, you can use a List of NameValuePair that can be passed directly to UrlEncodedFormEntity's constructor:

```
List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
parameters.add(new DoubleNameValuePair("lat", 1.0));
parameters.add(new DoubleNameValuePair("lng", 2.0));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) is a JDK class representing a generic tuple. Unfortunately, it's an inner class, making its use very, very verbose (especially once you use the type parameters). Additionally, using it with `double` values requires those to be wrapped (possibly using autoboxing), which adds more overhead.

You might want to write your own `StringDoublePair` class - it's not exactly difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a Map?

```
Map<String, Double> nameValuePairs = new HashMap<String, Double>();
nameValuePairs.put("lat", lat);
nameValuePairs.put("lng", lng);
```

Comment: Trying to send a HTTP request, If I do that I get a..

"The constructor UrlEncodedFormEntity(Map<String,Double>) is undefined"

error on line..

     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

Answer (score 1):

Like this maybe?

```
ArrayList<double[]> latLons = new ArrayList<double[]>();
latlons.add(new double[]{60.0, 20.0});
```

Comment: (I'm a bit lost with the question...)

Comment: Well, you see I'm making a HTTP request, I think need to map the lat value to a php lat variable and the long to a php variable. Sorry if it's obvious how to do this, I'm rather new to these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about NameValuePair used in Apache HttpClient. The value must be string. You have to convert it to String.

This is what I do,

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",""+lat));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng",""+lng));
```

Comment: problem is I then have to do some computation with the Double's so that wont exactly work :(